# ‘FaceRecognizer’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: opencv

I am trying to compile a program, I am trying to track an object using openCV.
Now whenever i compile the code i get the following error.

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:101:5: error: ‘FaceRecognizer’ was not declared in this scope
 Ptr model, mouthModel;
     ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:101:19: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 Ptr model, mouthModel;
                   ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:101:26: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘,’ token
 Ptr model, mouthModel;
                          ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp: In function ‘void snapshotCB(Fl_Widget*, void*)’:

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:232:40: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
    int predictedMouthLabel = mouthModel->predict(testSample);
                                        ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:242:31: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     int predictedLabel = model->predict(testSample);
                               ^
disguise_gui_1306.cpp:260:29: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
   int predictedLabel = model->predict(testSample);
                             ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp: In function ‘void 
trainFaceRecogniserModel(std::vector, std::vector)’:

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:394:39: error: ‘createEigenFaceRecognizer’ was not declared in this scope
     model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
                                       ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:395:10: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     model->train(img, lab);
          ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:416:39: error: ‘createEigenFaceRecognizer’ was not 
declared in this scope
     model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
                                       ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:417:10: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     model->train(images, labels);
          ^

disguise_gui_1306.cpp:432:15: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     mouthModel->train(mouthimages, mouthlabels);

While when the run the same on my friends laptop it compiles smoothly.
We are same OS(debian),OpenCV 3.0.0-rc1.
As per my research this problem should only arise if m using older version of openCV2.3.
I have been trying various solutions like adding contrib.hpp and all.
But nothing seems to help.

Kindly help.

Comment: for opencv3, you will additionally need the [contrib repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) , and use namespace cv::face

Comment: I have tried that.....i get everything as updated. So no use sadly !

Answer (score 2):

Was your opencv3 built with OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH option in `make`?

```
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=</path/to/opencv_contrib>/modules
```

Comment: No...checked the instruction that i followed while i was installing openCV. and nothing like this is mentioned in the installation guide.
Please guide to add extra modules. Thanks

Comment: I have also tried installing everything with the following command
"cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/isenses/Downloads/opencv_contrib-master/modules /home/isenses/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0-rc1"
Everything gets compiled and executed but still i keep getting the same error.

Comment: In your code, locate and change:

`Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();`

To: 

`Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> model = face::createEigenFaceRecognizer();`

Note added namespace before functions.

Comment: error: ‘face’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
 cv::Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> face::model, face::mouthModel;
I still got the same error while compiling.

Comment: You need to remove `face::` before `model` and `mouthModel` because they are local variable and they do not belong to the namespace `face`.

Comment: error: ‘face’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
 cv::Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> model, mouthModel;
Thanks again for the effort. I appreciate it. If you can guide me and help me understanding the reason of the error ,i will able to be a part of solution.

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention is i am using openCV3.0-rc1. And going through the installed folders and all i realized that many files are missing in 3 which is not the case in 2.4. or if i say it other way round, i get no missing files error when i use openCV2.4 rather than 3.Is it that files are still there but placed in diffrent manner or renamed?
For example while working on thiss new example i found that thee is no retina.hpp in version 3,but is there in 2.4.11. Can any one shed some light on the same please.

Comment: I haven't look into CV3.0-rc1 yet but my experience with the 3.0 stable version was smooth (except for those changes I mentioned above in my comments). So you might want to try the stable version when all else fails.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, first check if OpenCV was compiled with contrib modules as described in https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

then:

1. Add the inlude directories in your cmake CMakeLists.txt as described in
   https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html ; an example:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project( DisplayImage )
    find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
    include_directories( "/home/user/opencv-4.x","/home/user/opencv_contrib-4.x" )
    add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
    target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

2. In your program.cpp file include the libraries

```cpp
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/face.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

3. Follow the correct name spaces described per version of OpneCV in https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dd/d7c/classcv_1_1face_1_1EigenFaceRecognizer.html or de FaceRecognizer you use; for example

```cpp
    Ptr<cv::face::FaceRecognizer> model = cv::face::EigenFaceRecognizer::create();
```